# Embed Prerequisite for action buttons

Tags: html, css, styles, yammer

**From documentation:**

> Prerequisites
>
> To use Embed you need a HTML container 400 pixels or larger in your application. See below for a list of supported browsers.

1- I only need to embed 2 action buttons, like and follow, why would I need 400px container?

2- Is it possible that I style the divs containing these button by CSS, not by inline code?

Thanks.

Comment: And I just learned that because of this javascript sdk is breaking on line 5432.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the documentation available at https://developer.yammer.com/connect/. Please include a link to where you found your documentation in the future as it helps answer the question.

If you are embedding only like and follow buttons then you do not need the 400px container. The 400px container is for a subset of Yammer functionality, specifically: "Using embed, you can display My Feed, a Group Feed, a Topic Feed, a User Feed or an OG object feed." That is from the "Usage" section of "Yammer Embed" at the above link. It is designed to show feeds.

You are trying to use embedded actions. These are different than the feeds that require a 400px container; Like and Follow are **actions performed against Yammer** and feeds are **objects to be displayed from Yammer**. So you're fine without the container.

I do not know about styling the divs with CSS; I would recommend attempting it and seeing if it still works, but since you're talking about the application layer (and since Yammer only cares about the session layer when it comes to what you're doing) there should be nothing on the Yammer side that prevents you from styling it as you see fit.